# Is it possible to use the Bootstrap (v3) grid system inside an alert?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to use the Bootstrap grid system inside an alert? I'm trying to position a couple `.btn .btn-block` links side-by-side by putting them inside a `.col-xs-6`div, but they just spill out of the alert.

[JsFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/bxttfxkw/)

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <p>
        Alert text here.
    </p>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to remember the structure. container > row > column

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to wrap `col-*` classes with `.row` container:

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <p>Alert text here.</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bxttfxkw/1/

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="col-xs-12">
            Alert text here.
        </p>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button A</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Button B</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not just add the class 'row' to the alert div

Comment: Something like this would be a great time to use a snippet instead of jsfiddle.

Comment: @Daemedeor, you are right, but, I thought of separating the layers and provide an idea that even multiple rows can be added inside the alert.